# gitlab CI/CD error - remote-error: upload-pack: not our ref

Tags: gitlab-ci

We have Ansible code with submodules, one of which is called "tester". When I upload new code from any submodule, the CI/CD pipeline runs to test the code on various operating systems. This is the error I am seeing in the Gitlab CI/CD debug area:

```
 fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 13671… (a 40 alphanumeric string)
    Fetched in submodule path ‘roles/tester’ but it did not contain 13671… (same alphanumeric string above). Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

The CI/CD pipeline obviously fails and I have no idea why.

I did read somewhere to do a `git submodule deinit -f tester` When I did that the error is:

```
“error: pathspec ‘tester’ did not match any files known to git”
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?